# Recursive sum for each row

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Consider this testing data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS area (
    id integer,
    parent_id integer,
    name text,
    population integer
);

INSERT INTO area VALUES
    (1, NULL, 'North America', 0),
    (2, 1, 'United States', 0),
    (3, 1, 'Canada', 39),
    (4, 1, 'Mexico', 129),
    (5, 2, 'Contiguous States', 331),
    (6, 2, 'Non-contiguous States', 2);
```

| id | parent_id | name | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | North America | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | United States | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | Canada | 39 |
| 4 | 1 | Mexico | 129 |
| 5 | 2 | Contiguous States | 331 |
| 6 | 2 | Non-contiguous States | 2 |

Note that `population` (in millions) means here the additional population, excluding area's children.

How do I query the recursive sum for each row? I need to get something like this:

| name | sum |
| --- | --- |
| North America | 501 |
| United States | 333 |
| Canada | 39 |
| Mexico | 129 |
| Contiguous States | 331 |
| Non-contiguous States | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE parent AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        id AS root  -- Emit the root ID
    FROM area
    -- No WHERE clause, since we treat every row as a possible root
    
    UNION ALL   
    
    SELECT
        area.*,
        parent.root  -- Pass the root ID to the children
    FROM area
    JOIN parent ON parent.id = area.parent_id
)
SELECT
    name,
    sum
FROM (
    SELECT
        root,
        SUM(population)
    FROM parent
    GROUP BY root  -- Here is where we need the root IDs
) cumulative
JOIN area ON area.id = cumulative.root;  -- Use the nice names instead of IDs
```